# Show resize border for window panes

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

The resize handle/border on my explorer window is invisible.    I have a good idea of where the handle is, but I always have to hunt around.

Is there a way to show a border (where the yellow line is in the image)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this, I see, is by changing the Theme!

I don't have other themes installed, so I can only show you this on the [High Contrast Mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13862/windows-use-high-contrast-mode) that this is possible:

[image]
As you can see on my screenshot, there is a border!

It doesn't have to be a high contrast theme, you can mix it with your custom colors in the settings:
[image]

Besides the pre-installed classic themes on Windows 10, you can install [third-party themes](https://www.howtogeek.com/168270/how-to-install-custom-themes-and-visual-styles-in-windows/), where you can see the borderline. There are many custom themes to download on [deviantart](https://www.deviantart.com/customization/skins/windows/win10/popular-all-time/)!

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to modify those options without selecting a high contrast theme.  What's the path to get there?  Also, your settings looks like win7, is that what you're using?

Comment: @MikeH First choose the Theme you want. Then go below and click on colors. There you get the options, for the first just for the classic theme.